# How to clear datetimepicker value in windows application using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to clear my datetimepicker object value when i click on the clear button.

I just tried like this:

```
 datetimepicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
 datetimepicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Yes,it is cleared the value under the datetimepicker control. But the problem is after cleared the value then, I want to select the date after selection of the particular date, that date will not be displayed into datetimepicker object. What's the issue?

Comment: That's because you are resetting date format to invalid one. Just try setting datepicker value to null. By value I mean set property to null that returns you the selected date.

Comment: Yes, null not Nothing. Thanks @dotnetkid for the edit, I've been in the VB world too long :/.

Comment: @dotnetkid,it tells connot convert null to datetime because it is non-nullable value type message is shown

Comment: Got it. Didnt realise earlier. See my answer below. It's working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should meet your purpose. Logic is to reset date to minimum and then use `ValueChanged` event to hide it in display using what you already tried.

```
private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dateTimePicker1.Value == DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now; // This is required in order to show current month/year when user reopens the date popup.
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
    }
    else
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    }
}

private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime;
}
```

Comment: Yes,it's working but when i click on clear button it is cleared.But the format is changed.For ex: before click Clear: wed,Nov,18,2015,then after click on Clear: it cleared then now select the date from datetimepicker it gives:11/18/2015 but i want to show my pervious format.How can i?

Comment: What is confusing in that? Restore (set) original format in `else` condition instead of `DateTimePickerFormat.Short`