# Clear the DateTimePicker control in c# winfoms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to clear the DateTimePicker control value when i click on clear button but i can't do that with simple double qoutes, So please help me

```
tbAddress.Text = "";
        dtpBirth.Value = "";
        cBoxGender.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear datetimepicker value in windows application using c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772295/how-to-clear-datetimepicker-value-in-windows-application-using-c)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, i searched it but not solved what i want to that's why i post a question

Comment: this should do the trick `dtpBirth.CustomFormat = " "; dtpBirth.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;` it will clear the input box.

Comment: Then you are either doing something wrong or you need to rephrase your question. The way it is now it is identical (and therefore a duplicate).

Comment: @SeM Thanks man .. it solved ma problem... :)

Comment: @khaafi You're welcome. I'll add it to answers, mark it to close the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
dtpBirth.CustomFormat = " ";
dtpBirth.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

it will clear the input box.

Answer (score 0):

try is

`dateTimePickerDOB.Value = DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime`

in this your date and time going to be minimum date and time in your DateTimePicker and `dateTimePickerDOB` mean your Design(name)

or

try this for clear the date

`dateTimePicker_dob.Text = string.Empty;`

in here `dateTimePickerDOB` mean your Design(name)

Answer (score -1):

The `DateTimePicker.Value` is from type `DateTime` and not a `String`.

```
dtpBirth.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: You are correct, but that doesn't answer the question (which by the way is a duplicate anyway)

Comment: @wudge i want to clear the field for new entry not to populate with the current date

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dateTimePicker1.Value == DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now; // This is required in order to show current month/year when user reopens the date popup.
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
    }
    else
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    }
}

private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime;
}
```

Comment: datetimepicker1.Value = null won't work because a DateTime can not be set to null.

Comment: not working and set the `dtpBirth.Value` to `Null` is not working either because it is a non nullable

Comment: You're right, but the first example i give works perfectly. Thanks