# VB.Net: Prevent DateTimePicker control to default to First day of the month

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetimepicker

For the VB.Net DateTimePicker control, I need to prevent it defaulting to a value(First day of the month) when the Calendar Icon is clicked.
The *ValueChanged* event does not help in this case as it gets called even if the calendar icon is clicked.

So when the Calendar icon (as highlighted in the image) is clicked, we should see a calendar from which user can make the selection and then the date should be set to the control.

[image]

Comment: By default, it defaults not to the first day of the month, but to the current date. What have you changed? Would be nice to see some code... Even if you have done `DateTimePicker1.MaxDate = New Date(2022, 1, 11)`, the 11th is still selected because today is the 12th.

Comment: So I have a field VisitDate that is the reference point of TestDate field.
The value of VisitDate is set to MaxDate of TestDate.

Scenario 1: Working fine.
When the VisitDate is set to Current month and value is selected greater than today's date.Then the TestDate control works fine and it does not take any default date.

Scenario 2: Issue here

Comment: Scenario 2: Issue here
When the VisitDate is set to Current month and value is selected less than today's date. Then the TestDate control defaults it to first day of month.

Example: VisitDate is 10-Jan 2022, and TestDate selected is 6 Jan 2022, then it defaults the TestDate to first day (1 Jan 2022) even if the Calendar icon is clicked,

Comment: You can remove the formatted date from the textbox with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33772742/832052) but I haven't found a way to deselect the day in the calendar

Comment: Thank you for your response @djv, but I have already tried the option given in the link. It does not seem to work as I need.